# Is it safe to use one login page for multiple guards?

Tags: laravel

So I'm using one login page for multiple guards, web guard and admin guard.

I'm overriding the "attemptLogin" method to check the credentials in each table one by one and also preventing duplicate username by using unique rule in each table.

My question, is it safe to do this?

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $userAttempt = Auth::guard('web')->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
    if($userAttempt == false){
         return Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
        );
    }
    return $userAttempt;
}
```

Comment: Does the possibility of a user registering in the page with the same credentials as any of the admins? In that case that admin would not be able to login.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish exactly with the admin guard. But maybe using a Middleware or a package like [spatie/permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) is a better solution.

Comment: No i'm disabling registration for users. I'm using multiple guards for different purposes, I'll be also using Spatie package. anyhow i'm just trying to find out is it safe to use another login page for admin or just using the same page??

Comment: As long as you check all your conditions and use safety measure properly to guard it is absolutely safe using same view for multi-auth.

Comment: @iamawesome, Thanks